# White mold like grown on Alienwares Rubberized surfaces, any tips to deal with it?

Tags: laptop

This may not be the right forum for this q, indeed I cant imagine what is.. but the people here might have faced this, so I am trying here.. Be warned, the images might be little gross..

I have this alienware from my friend who has left it in a backpack for a few years. When opened now it appears to have small white dots all over its cover, and this seems much worse inside. Any ideas on what this is, how to deal with it, or anything at all.... ??

Kinda looks like it got into the screen as well
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes;  I would agree the screen is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some rubbing alcohol, just *dampening* a clean cloth, and wiping the keyboard. If that works, try it on the outside of the screen. However, if there's mold growing *between* layers of the display, you'd either need to replace the display or just use an external monitor. Since Alienware makes high-end PC's, you might actually prefer using it with a mechanical-switch keyboard and a good quality display, an excellent gaming combo. (For a Chromebook, though, it would neither be cost effective nor very satisfying).